# Is there a way to add system date or time in print composer?

Tags: qgis, printing

Is there a way in the Print Composer of QGIS to create a label that will automatically update the date (systems date) instead of having a label that you have to manually have to update?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, you can add

```
format_date( now(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

---

This used to be the old syntax:

```
$CURRENT_DATE(yyyy-MM-dd)
```

Comment: In QGIS3, if adding as a label in your Layout, you could add this code to the Label item's 'Main properties' text box  [% format_date( now(),'MM/dd/yyyy') %]

Comment: It it possible to choose the output language? I would like to show the date in French fr_FR format.

Comment: Found it: [%format_date(now(), 'dd MMMM yyyy', 'fr_FR')%]

Comment: $CURRENT_DATE(yyyy-MM-dd) still works, and without an expression. https://twitter.com/qgis/status/144365563752349696